# How do I access '/tmp/mysqld.sock' with 1and1 as my host?

Tags: mysql

I am getting the error "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysqld.sock' (2)"
I know this question MAY LOOK like it has been asked before.
I know this question has been asked before when it involves 1and1 as a host provider.
My issue is that the /tmp folder is no where to be found
My 1and1 host provides me with a logs folder, that's it.

I have never ran into this issue before. Honestly, I don't even know what's going on.
My debugging/test code looks exactly like this except for the password part.

my best guess is that 1and1 is going through some changes or had something fail on their side. Something I can't see. That would mean that this will be resolved with time.

```
$host_name  = "db558469055.db.1and1.com";
$database   = "db558469055";
$user_name  = "dbo558469055";
$password   = "*******";

$connect = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);
$query = "INSERT INTO `db558469055`.`boxes` (`id`, `sid`, `link`) VALUES (NULL, MD5('c'), 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tluAWgAoJts')";
mysql_query($query);
echo '---------'.mysql_error();
//is stackoverflow's formatting this obnoxious on purpose? jfc
```

Comment: Don't mix `mysqli` and `mysql_query`. You're making a mess of things here. Try reading a [guide on best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/) to avoid creating huge problems. Using MD5 passwords is worthless.

Comment: That error means you're trying to connect to a database on `localhost`, not on a network server. Are you sure you set `$host_name`?

Comment: You use `mysql_query` without any connection, as of that a new connection with the default settings will be created (`[...]If no such link is found, it will try to create one as if mysql_connect() was called with no arguments.[...]`) that's why your error occurs. Like `tadman` already said you should not use `mysql_query` when you want to use `mysqli`

Comment: I copied the connection code from 1and1's "quick PHP dbConnect code"
I never knew there was a difference.

I should stop copy and pasting and probably sit down and read a manual or something. I had no idea Mysqli was even a thing.
No wonder I didn't catch it.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the connection code from 1and1's "quick PHP dbConnect code" I never knew there was a difference. I should stop copy and pasting and probably sit down and read a manual or something. I had no idea Mysqli was even a thing. No wonder I didn't catch it.

The true answer here is "stop being a lazy script kiddy & read a book".

```
mysql_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);
//not
mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);
```